# Как создать бота для Телеграм?

Tags: lua

Я недавно создал рп чат в Телеграме, но выходит трудно без бота и мне нужно сделать простого бота, под ответом которого есть кнопки (допустим) "Построить", "Начать битву". И который будет ещё вызывать игрока через "@", плюс ещё в определённое время писать что-то (допустим) "На вас напали" 16:00. Желательно бы написать как сделать кнопки под сообщением бота, как вписать код для функции и работает ли код Lua для бота?

Answer (score 0):

пример бота телеграм на Lua [тут](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/samples)

библиотека для разработки ботов на Lua [тут](https://github.com/ldb/lua-telegram-bot)